# How to rename the Sandbox text in Dynamic CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

[image: Click to find screenshot]

I want to rename the SANDBOX text in navigation bar.

Any idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SANDBOX` text inside Dynamics CRM Online sandbox instances is not customizable

Answer (score 1):

You can change this using the theme editor under Settings > Customisations.  More info available in [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/21a166a0-d25e-4260-a1e4-2ddc528787c2) technet article.

From the screenshot linked I assume you're using either CRM 2015 or 2016 rather than 2011 based on the tag.  Please update this if I'm correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm using CRM 2015. Using theme editor it is pot possible to change the SANDBOX text to RESTRICTED.

Comment: Guido is correct.  I wasn't aware of the label that's applied to sandbox online instances.